# deleting files and folders via a .sh file

Tags: linux, sh

I have a file in my root hosting directory which I am running via a cron job once a day. The goal of the file is to once a day delete all files and sub directories within a folder.

My issue is I confirmed my cron is running the file. However the file does not seem to be working. Meaning it is not deleting all sub folders and files ?

Below is my code

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -rf /home/plainfie/public_html/var/cache/*
rm -rf /home/plainfie/public_html/var/session/*
rm -rf /home/plainfie/public_html/var/report/*
rm -rf /home/plainfie/public_html/media/catalog/product/cache/
```

This is on a Cpanel (linux) based hosting account and I have the file set with 0777 file permission.

Comment: I would consider redirecting output from your cron to a log file and see if that gets you anywhere. You should just be able to add something like `&> /var/log/mylogfile.log` to the end of your cron entry.

Comment: Change the `rm -rf` to `rm -rvf` and, in cron, run the script as `./script > script.log 2>&1`. This will give you a verbose output for further investigation.

Comment: I added &> /var/log/mylogfile.log to the end of my cron job and that just took the contents of my above code and wrote it to a log file with no error message?

Answer (score 0):

ok I found my issue the hosting account did not have access to ssh so the file was blocked from being run.